# How to include optionally downloadable audio files in my android app?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app which has some audio files(.mp3). I have placed these files in res/raw folder. I want to make some these files to be downloaded only if user wishes to download later on. I do not want these to be shipped along with APK file. Please suggest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can put those files on some web server and give option to user if he/she wants to download those files, user can download from the webserver. Shipping those files with APK will result in increased size of APK as well. For example there can be a list view of sound files in app, each linked with some download URL. On user request, if he agrees to download, you can initiate a `asynctask` in `onclick` and play the file in `onPostExecute` after the files has been downloaded.

A simple check can be placed to check if file has been already downloaded or not and initiate `asynctask`based on the boolean returned from that check. I hope this helps.